# How to merge multiple conversations for the same contact into a single converstation

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms

How do I merge multiple conversations for the same contact into a single conversation in SMS app?

Comment: They are supposed to be in same conversation. Did this seperation happened after new Outlook.com migration?

Comment: I'm talking about stock SMS app not Outlook app.

Comment: I am also taking about the Messaging app / Stock SMS app. It displays the contacts from your Outlook / MS account. After the migration to new outlook.com interface I faced numerous errors such as loosing of contact pics, seperate conversations in sms app, seperate call history in phone app, etc... I am just asking Iif you faced the same issue

Comment: I didn't know about the migration. I thought something weird going on my device or People app. I had the same problems you mentioned above.

Comment: As far as I know there is no solution to this problem. However since a lot of people have reported this problem I expect a solution soon. I will post any solution if I come across one.